# grep and sed to capture parameter in file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed

I have a line which has some parameters that I want to grab. What is the best way to do this?

Example line is :

```
l1_user_instr hits=0035191479 misses=0000013657
l1_user_data hits=0009562889 misses=0001215170
```

I want to write a script which gives `hits=xx` and `miss=yy` for a particular configuration.

```
grep l1_user_instr_hits | sed ?
```

I am not an expert in sed and hence the question.

Comment: sed  's/=/ = /' total | grep l1_user_instr . This command just changes the first "=" to " = " but not the second =. Any reason why ??

Comment: you need to add the `global` function. Try: `sed 's/=/ = /g'`

Comment: is it because new string " = " contains the old string "=" , i.e. recursive

Comment: can you please explain me the reasoning behind global keyword

Comment: `sed` will make the substitution on every occurrence of the pattern match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are looking for, but judging from comments in other answers I think you want the ability to get either the number of hits or the number of misses, and nothing else.  For example, when looking for hits on configuration 'l1_user_data', you want the output to be exactly:

`0009562889`

An easy thing to do (you could add a better interface) would be something like:

```
awk -v f=3 -v c=l1_user_instr -F ' *|=' '$0 ~ c {print $f}' input
```

By setting FS to split the line on `=` as well as white space, we've made the number of hits field 3, and the number of misses is field 5.  Set the variable c to the string you want to match, and set f to the field you want to display (either 3 or 5).  Note that you might want to handle tabs as well as spaces in FS  (there are a lot of things that could/should be done to improve this interface, but for a one-off, this is fine).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `awk` would suit your needs. Try this:

```
awk '/l1_user_instr/ { print $2,$3 }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
hits=0035191479 misses=0000013657
```

HTH

Comment: i want the number xx here (hits=xx). awk cannot give me that right?

Comment: please add example output. it's not clear what you're looking for. cheers.

Comment: example output is a bash variable which contains the hits and misses for each line(config).

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` (if I get correctly what you want):

```
sed '/l1_user_instr/ s/.*\(hits=\d\+\) \(misses=\d\+\)[^0-9]*$/\1\n\2/;q' INPUTFILE
```

Basically it will search for matching `l1_user_instr` line, and on that line creates two groups for matching the required data, then prints them new line separated, and exits. The `awk` solution is simmilar:

```
awk '/l1_user_instr/ {printf("%s\n%s\n",$2,$3) ; exit}' INPUTFILE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS=" =" read -r type _ hits _ misses
do
    echo "Type: $type, Hits: $hits, Misses: $misses"
done < inputfile
```

Example output:

```
Type: l1_user_instr, Hits: 0035191479, Misses: 0000013657
Type: l1_user_data, Hits: 0009562889, Misses: 0001215170
```